# How to draw a polygon with height exactly equals to the text's height

Tags: minipage

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and XeLaTeX.
I have a minipage with some formatted text:

```
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}%
    \centering\small\textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse elementum luctus odio sit amet mollis.}%
\end{minipage}
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]

And this is what I want:
[image]

How can I draw a polygon with exactly the same height as a text's height and with same y-coordinate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox); page breaks are allowed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{112,146,190}

\newlength\myleni
\newlength\mylenii
\newlength\quotewidth
\setlength\myleni{20pt}
\setlength\mylenii{40pt}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
breakable,
freelance,
remember,
colback=white,
center upper,
coltext=myblue,
left=1.5cm,
right=1.5cm,
top=0pt,
bottom=0pt,
fontupper=\itshape,
frame code={%
  \fill[myblue] let 
    \p1= (interior.north),
    \p2= (interior.south) in   
   (current page.west|-interior.north west) -- 
    ([xshift=-\myleni]interior.north west) --
    ([xshift=-\mylenii]interior.north west|-( 0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1 ) --
    ([xshift=-\myleni]interior.south west) --
    (current page.west|-interior.south west);
  \fill[myblue] let 
    \p1= (interior.north),
    \p2= (interior.south) in   
   (current page.east|-interior.north east) -- 
    ([xshift=\myleni]interior.north east) --
    ([xshift=\mylenii]interior.north east|-( 0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1 ) --
    ([xshift=\myleni]interior.south east) --
    (current page.east|-interior.south east);
  }
}

\begin{document}


\lipsum[4]
\begin{mybox}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse elementum luctus odio sit amet mollis.
\end{mybox}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's really great and highly customizable solution, I'll defenitely use it!

Answer (score 5):

Here’s a solution using TikZ. Note that the quotes can't span over pages.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength{\quotewidth}
\setlength{\quotewidth}{0.75\textwidth}
\newlength{\bannercorner}
\setlength{\bannercorner}{2mm}
\colorlet{bannercolor}{blue!70}

\NewEnviron{bannerquote}{%
    \par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}\noindent
    \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (quote) [
            text width = \quotewidth,
            align=center,
            font=\small\itshape,
            inner sep=0pt,
            outer xsep=2mm,
            text=bannercolor,
        ] {\BODY};
        \useasboundingbox (quote.north east) rectangle (quote.south west);
        \fill [bannercolor] (quote.north west) -- ($(quote.west)+(-\bannercorner,0)$)
            -- (quote.south west) -- ++(-\paperwidth,0) -- ++($(quote.north)-(quote.south)$)
            -- cycle;
        \fill [bannercolor] (quote.north east) -- ($(quote.east)+(\bannercorner,0)$)
            -- (quote.south east) -- ++(\paperwidth,0) -- ++($(quote.north)-(quote.south)$)
            -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hfill\mbox{}%
    \par\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
    \noindent\ignorespaces
}


\usepackage{lipsum}% blind text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{bannerquote}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse elementum luctus odio sit amet mollis.
\end{bannerquote}

\lipsum[1]



\end{document}
```

- `\node` creats a box of with `\bannerwidth` containing the centered quote text.
- `\useasboundingbox` make sure that the following banner won't affect placing of the box.
- The two `\fill` commands draw the banner relative the the quote text contained in a `node` named `quote`.

Answer (score 2):

No `tcolorbox`, no `tikz`, and shorter that some of the other solutions.  It does not break across pages, because the result is in a boxed macro, not an environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newsavebox\txbox
\newcommand\polyquote[2]{%
  \vspace{2pt}%
  \fboxsep=-0.4pt%
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \sbox{\txbox}{\fboxsep=1pt\colorbox{white}{%
    \parbox{#1}{\color{blue!70}\centering\small\itshape#2}}}%
  {\centering%
  \hsmash{\stackon[0pt]{\colorbox{blue!70}{%
    \rule{0ex}{\ht\txbox+\dp\txbox}\hspace{\paperwidth}}}{%
    \abovebaseline[\dp\txbox]{\color{white}%
    \scaleleftright{\blacktriangleleft\kern-1.5pt}{\usebox{\txbox}}%
      {\kern-1.5pt\blacktriangleright}}}}%
  \vspace{2pt}%
  \par}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\polyquote{3.5in}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit. Suspendisse elementum luctus odio sit amet mollis.%
}
\lipsum[4]
\polyquote{2.5in}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor \\sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing\\ elit. Suspendisse\\ elementum luctus odio\\ sit amet mollis.%
}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]